# Cannot debug in VS2008 with Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis, windows-7, debugging

Since installing Windows 7, I cannot debug a website.  I am an administrator on the machine, but when I try to debug, it says: Unable to start debugging on the web server. YOu do not have permissions to debug the web server process. You need to either be running as the same user account as the web ser, or have administrator privlege."
I have IIS set up on my machine and am using that as a custom server on port 81...

Any ideas?

Comment: Change the account that the application pool runs in to the same account you're logged in as, stop and start IIS and the app pool, then try again.

Comment: tried this too...same result...I had this all working on Vista so I believe it is a change with Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I thought User Account control was more of a notification service in Windows 7 and had left it on. However, this is not the case and when I turned it off, my problem was solved...

Victor's solution would have worked, but since I publish to a mapped network drive, it did not like my credentials.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Does the User Account control have to really be turned off?  Seems like this is defeating the purpose of having it.

Comment: There are several levels of it, but after beating my head against the desk all day yesterday, I decided I didn't care any longer.  Maybe a less secure uac setting would suffice...

Plus, I really only use the machine for development so I am not that concerned with getting something nasty on it..

Answer (score 2):

Try running Visual Studio as Administrator.
Right click its icon -> "Run as Administrator"

Comment: This does work, but I use Visual Studio to publish to a mapped network drive.  So when I run as administrator, it gives me an error trying to access the mapped network drive (even when i specify connection credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (check authentication in IIS as well)

1. In the Internet Explorer, "Tools" Menu, select "Internet Options".
2. Switch to "Security" Tab.
3. Click on "Internet" (The Globe Icon. Its actually the default selected).
4. Click on "Custom Level" in the bottom.
5. Scroll down to find the "User Authentication" section.
6. Select "Automatic logon with current username and password".
7. Click "Ok" twice to exit.

For a complete list of solutions on solving the debugger issues:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290100(VS.71).aspx

Comment: This did not work...I should have specified I am using Visual Studio 2008

Comment: Oh sorry I saw you did specify that, some of the tips might still work for 2008 though.